# group by and subtract first occurrence and last occurrence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 code    date         time         dip     flag   tank   qty
 123     2018-12-23   08:00:00     389     0      1      1300
 123     2018-12-23   09:00:00     380     0      1      1250
 123     2018-12-23   10:00:00     378     0      1      1200
 123     2018-12-23   11:00:00     345     1      1      1150
 123     2018-12-23   12:00:00     342     1      1      1100
 123     2018-12-23   13:00:00     340     1      1      1050
 123     2018-12-23   14:00:00     338     1      1      1000
 123     2018-12-23   15:00:00     380     0      1      1500
 123     2018-12-23   16:00:00     340     1      1      1000
 123     2018-12-23   17:00:00     340     1      1      1000
 123     2018-12-23   08:00:00     389     0      2      1300
 123     2018-12-23   09:00:00     380     0      2      1250
 123     2018-12-23   10:00:00     378     0      2      1200
 123     2018-12-23   11:00:00     345     1      2      1150
 123     2018-12-23   12:00:00     342     1      2      1100
 123     2018-12-23   13:00:00     340     1      2      1050
 123     2018-12-23   14:00:00     338     1      2      1000
```

I want to find how many times `dip` is below 350, till what time(in hours) it remained below 350 and what is the quantity sold when below 350
Below is my desired dataframe. I have already set the flag as 1 when there is a dip less than 350

```
 code    date        tank     frequency    qty_sold    time
 123     2018-12-23  1        4            150         3
 123     2018-12-23  2        4            150         3
```

I am able to find the frequency with groupby. need some help in finding other two

```
  df_agg= df.groupby(['code','date','tank']).agg({'flag':['sum']}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create datetimes column
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

#add aggregation by first and last 
df_agg= df[df['dip'] < 350].groupby(['code','date','tank']).agg({'flag':['sum'], 
                                                                'datetime':['first','last'],
                                                                'qty':['first','last']})
#flatten MultiIndex
df_agg.columns = df_agg.columns.map('_'.join)

#substract columns, timedeltas convert to hours
df_agg['qty_sold'] = df_agg.pop('qty_first') - df_agg.pop('qty_last') 
df_agg['time'] = (df_agg.pop('datetime_last') - df_agg.pop('datetime_first'))
                       .dt.total_seconds().div(3600).astype(int)
#rename column and create default index
df_agg = df_agg.rename(columns={'flag_size':'frequency'}).reset_index()

print (df_agg)
   code        date  tank  flag_sum  qty_sold  time
0   123  2018-12-23     1         4       150     3
1   123  2018-12-23     2         4       150     3
```

EDIT:

Solution working if no missing values in `date` or `time` values and frequency of datetimes is one hour difference.

Idea is create new helper column `g` for groups if difference is more like `1` hour and last aggregate sum per first 3 levels:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

df_agg= df[df['dip'] < 350].copy()

df_agg['g'] = (df_agg.groupby(['code','date','tank'])['datetime'].diff()
                     .ne(pd.Timedelta(1, 'H'))
                     .cumsum())

df_agg= df_agg.groupby(['code','date','tank','g']).agg({'flag':['sum'], 
                                                        'datetime':['first','last'],
                                                        'qty':['first','last']})
df_agg.columns = df_agg.columns.map('_'.join)
df_agg['qty_sold'] = df_agg.pop('qty_first') - df_agg.pop('qty_last') 
df_agg['time'] = ((df_agg.pop('datetime_last') - df_agg.pop('datetime_first'))
                         .dt.total_seconds().div(3600).astype(int))

df_agg = (df_agg.rename(columns={'flag_size':'frequency'})
                .sum(level=[0,1,2])
                .reset_index()
          )

print (df_agg)
   code        date  tank  flag_sum  qty_sold  time
0   123  2018-12-23     1         6       150     4
1   123  2018-12-23     2         4       150     3
```

Comment: just one question, what if there are multiple instances of flags less than 350 as edited in the question. Still this answer holds true? Now in the question there are instances below 350 are from 11:00 - 14:00 and 16:00-17:00, in a solution we are taking first and last entry.

Comment: @Neil - yes, it working this way - filter first by `df[df['dip'] < 350]`, so get all rows bellow 350. Then if multiple groups of datetimes like in edited answer then for first and last datetimes are used first datetimes from first group (11:00) and for last datetimes last one from last group (17:00). So difference is not correct, because 17:00 - 11:00 count also datetimes not in group (14:00 to  16:00). So answer has to be changed, please give me some time

Comment: what if my frequency of time is half an hour? can I edit your code as `pd.Timedelta(0.5, 'H')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
# to get till what time (hour)
df.loc[df['dip'].lt(350),'time'].dt.hour.max()

# what is the quantity sold
df.loc[df['dip'].lt(350),'qty'].sum()
```